# How to filter points in one go by setting extent area around line?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, editing, filter, attribute-index

I have a large set of data points which are falling away from my study area(Which is not required)Pls see image attached. I need to filter points which are falling within a radius of say 2km from the ***red line*** (POINT A AND B). How should I do in one command? As I have lot more files with a similar problem.

[image]

After I enter:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for line in layer.selectedFeatures():
    print line.geometry().exportToWkt()
```

in python console, nothing is seen.

[image]

Where do i see the output?

[Here is a link to the data.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18gmn1blUgdE8fr1eiY2TVeaB2o82DGh2)

Comment: Is your red line actually a line layer or is it points from the same layer?

Comment: It's a Line layer. Points also exists on that line..

Answer (score 1):

Select your red line and type the following into the **Python Console** to get its coordinates in WKT (Well-Known Text) format:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for line in layer.selectedFeatures():
    print line.geometry().exportToWkt()
```

It should print something like:

```
LineString (-0.35817092 2.07212114, 0.01439589 0.14525215)
```

Copy this then select your point layer and run the **Select by expression** tool either from the menubar (`View > Select`) or from the *Processing Toolbox*.

Then use an expression like (assuming your CRS units are in metres):

```
distance(geom_from_wkt('LineString (-0.35817092 2.07212114, 0.01439589 0.14525215)'), $geometry) <= 2000
```

This should select all points within 2 km of your line. You can filter them in whatever way you want (e.g. save them in a new shapefile, give them a new attribute which you can use for styling etc.).

---

Example of selecting points (highlighted in yellow) within 500 m from the red line (using marker points):

[image: Example]

---

I don't think there is a single command to achieve this other than creating a script.

Comment: When I type                                                                                              layer = iface.activeLayer()
for line in layer.selectedFeatures():
    print line.geometry().exportToWkt()                                                                                      and run, nothing happens in python console.. its not printing anything

Comment: I have not worked with Python console before... Please bear with me...

Comment: Don't worry about it :). You need to select the line layer from the _Layers Panel_ and the line your interested in, they type the above in the Python Console :)

Comment: I did... Nothing happened... It's not printing anything...

Comment: @AmarCr - Would it be possible for you to share your line layer and a point layer?

Comment: When i run the script, it shows like this execfile(u'c:/users/sasidh~1/appdata/local/temp/tmp7ur6dx.py'.encode('mbcs'))

Comment: How do u want me to share my files with you?? can u pls send your mail id, or mail me at amarocks9@gmail.com

Comment: @AmarCr - No need to put the code into a script (that just overcomplicates things). From the menubar, go to `Plugins > Python Console` and copy/paste the code into the console. Ideally, you should upload files to a public server, (i.e. Dropbox, Google Drive) so that others could access it. You should create a copy of your files and edit out sensitive information which might be stored in the attributes and then upload. You can [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/267361/edit) your question to include the web link to your files.

Comment: here is the link.. pls check and let me know https://drive.google.com/open?id=18gmn1blUgdE8fr1eiY2TVeaB2o82DGh2

Comment: @AmarCr - [It works fine for me](https://imgur.com/a/6E618). Did you select the actual line in your line layer (i.e. from menubar `View > Select > Select Feature` and then click your line)? If nothing is selected, nothing is printed.

Comment: Yes I have selected actual line

Comment: @AmarCr - Is it highlighted in the layer's Attribute Table?

Comment: Got it. The line should be edited(toggle editing), inorder to generate points.

Comment: LineStringZ (77.6227673353830312 12.91733908522803986 0, 77.62193729715029633 12.91859278877537953 0, 77.6211152338158854 12.91971733293357083 .......)

Comment: @AmarCr - Well done, although it shouldn't need to be in edit mode but you got the same result I did. After you import the csv file as points, I suggest you save this as a shapefile and set the CRS to a local UTM so that the units are measured in metres.

Comment: Further I have one more problem. How can i use this script to filter out data in MSSQL(My source of data) , I need to import points which are only in radius of 2km from the line.

Comment: @AmarCr - I think you should ask this as a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and mention exactly what you have, what you want and what you have tried.